# How to record voice for incoming and outgoing calls ?

Tags: android, phone-call

I got code to record voice during incoming and outgoing calls but not getting how to link this code to call that to record the voice when there is any incoming and outgoing calls?

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple, It is totally based on the event occuraing. Let me give you a logic for this.

- Create a BroadcastReceviver which will check for the incoming and outgoing calls.
- Create a method which will record the voice for both the event.
- Whenever the BroadcastReceiver fires just call that method init.
- Done.

e.g.

Declare receiver in AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name=".CallRecoderBroadcast">   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Give read phone state permission in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

For recording and saving to SD card follow these tutorials,

http://www.devlper.com/2010/12/android-audio-recording-part-1/

http://www.devlper.com/2010/12/android-audio-recording-part-2/

Comment: ok thank u .... i and i got complete android code but how to excute in emulater in emulator their is no option to call....

Comment: You can't execute it in emulator as it doesnt have SIM card

Comment: and i want to store recorded voice in somewhere in mobile,how to set path?

Comment: no i am biggner,  recorder.setOutputFile("/D:/sound"); i need to set path here.

Comment: @user3270129, I have updated my answer with useful tutorial link, please check it.

Comment: and how to convert project into android apk.

Comment: when you will execute your project, it will automatically create .apk file inside the bin folder of your project's folder.

Comment: Yes, if mobile phone is attached then .apk file will automatically run in to mobile phone, You dont need to externally transfer it. :)

Comment: that means if we connect mobile  to computer then we need to send that  apk file ? and how it atomaticaly execute?

Comment: What I am saying is, while running a code, if your phone is attached with the computer the output .apk file will automatically execute in mobile rather than in emulator. So you dont need to manually install it in Phone, that part is automatically taken care by eclipse.

Comment: ok...and once it executing in mobile and want to record voice whather voice recorded automatical?....

Comment: Yes it recorder will start automatically based on the event of incoming or outgoing call.

Comment: Tutorial links are not working. Is there any other tutorial?